# How do I send values with POST when redirecting in Perl?

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I have two values one for name and another for password that I would like to pass to another page if the user entered the right combination. If the user did I know that I can redirect by including the values in the query string like:

```
$cgi->redirect('http:someotherpage.com?username=$username&password=$password');
```

but that is using a GET request, is there a way to do the same thing using a POST or is there another way to pass on the values when redirecting in Perl? I know that JSP has a method called RequestDispatcher is there something like that in Perl if the POST is not available?

Edit: I found this link [CGI Application Dispatch](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Application-Dispatch-3.12/lib/CGI/Application/Dispatch.pm) earlier but it's a little technical so I don't know if this is the right tool for the job.

Edit: I'm using CGI.pm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing a HTTP redirect you can only give the URL of the new target. This means, there is no way to specify any data for the POST request, because they are outside the URL.

From my understanding the RequestDispatcher from JSP does not send a HTTP redirect response, but forwards the current request internally inside the JSP application. This would be comparable to let your CGI script just dispatch the current request to another script on the same server, without doing a redirect through the browser. Details how to do this would depend on the framework you use (e.g. Dancer, Mojolicious, Catalyst ... or plain CGI.pm)

Comment: if it's not too much trouble, could you provide an example of the code how one CGI script could dispatch the current request to another script on the same server?

Comment: That would be a lot of work for nothing. put the logic of script2 you need in script2 in a module to be used by both scripts.

Comment: @ikegami I'm sorry, what is script2?

Comment: @Stochastic13: write a single web-application (like with JSP) instead of using multiple independent scripts. Merge the functionality of all these scripts as separate functions into a single script and decide based on PATH_INFO to which function you dispatch. Then your "redirect" is just the call of another function in the same script. Better yet, use a modern framework, because [CGI.pm must die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tu6_3fZbWYw).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Would that work if I wanted for the user upon entering the right login information to be presented with another view, that is completely replacing the HTML/CSS that the login form was on with HTML/CSS for the page when the user has passed the verification process?  And which modern framework would you recommend learning instead of CGI.pm?

Comment: Why do you want a second script? Why can't you just add the functionality into your first script?

Comment: @Borodin I don't want the second scritp, I just don't want for the user to see the login boxes after his password got verified, so I was thinking that I repaint the page with whole new HTML, but I don't know how that could be done in one script without redirecting the user to another page.

Comment: Like you do for every other request: print out the HTML to STDOUT after outputting a header.

Comment: Thanks, guys sorry for so many basic questions, but I've never programmed in Perl before yesterday.

Comment: @Stochastic13: maybe you should have a look at the [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) framework. I've never worked with it but I've heard a lot of good things about it, especially that they are very supportive. They have tutorials etc where you might start to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I had a need to redirect a page and include POST data.  Searching for a solution only uncovered posts saying that it was impossible to do. So... challenge accepted.

First the why: I have a perl cgi that is called with POST data, and puts up a form (text input, checkboxes, etc.) based on the passed data.  The user makes their changes/selections and submits the form.  The target is a cgi that processes the POST data and performs the necessary updates to a database.  I then wanted to immediately redisplay the first form, so the results of the changes could be seen.  While there is minimal POST data necessary to display the form, I was loath to send it as a GET.

**My solution:**

After processing the POST data, the cgi generates another HTML page, which includes:

- A form with the POST data to be passed and desired target
- A javascript function that submits the form
- An 'onload' event in the BODY tag that executes the javascript

The loading of the above page is almost unnoticeable (if I didn't know it was happening, I probably wouldn't be aware of it.)  And it works like a charm.