# Redirect using post in perl mason

Tags: perl, redirect, mason

Currently, I am redirecting like this

```
$Request->redirect( ( 
    url => $Std->url( 
        '/a/b/c/d', { 
            protocol => 'https', 
            get => { 'key1' => '123', 'key2' => '456' } 
        } 
    ) 
) );
```

Is there any way to do a Post redirect or replicate a POST otherwise ?

Comment: ***"Is there any way to do a Post redirect of replicate a POST otherwise?"*** I don't know what that means. And your redirect uses `GET`

Comment: sorry was a typing mistake

Answer (score -1):

[How do I send values with POST when redirecting in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353474/how-do-i-send-values-with-post-when-redirecting-in-perl)

It appears that we can not send post data during redirection.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect also seems pertinent to this.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).